# Using Perfect-Markdown, tables are not rendering like GitHub's UI

Tags: swift, markdown, perfect

I'm using the Perfect framework and importing Perfect-Markdown to render my README.md on the landing page of my REST service.

Simply put, I'm attempting to render a table that looks something like:

```
| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    $1 |
```

My handler is:

```
func handler(request: HTTPRequest, response: HTTPResponse) {
    response.setHeader(.contentType, value: "text/html")
    let source = getSourceDir(for: #file)
    let data = FileManager.init().contents(atPath: "\(source)README2.md")
    let string = String.init(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
    let html = string?.markdownToHTML
    response.appendBody(string: html!)
    response.completed()
}
```

getSourceDir() is simply applying the path of the file in the project.

I really want to the table to display like it does with GitHub's UI, but instead the table displays like:

```
Tables  Are Cool
col 3 is    right-aligned   $1600
col 2 is    centered    $12
zebra stripes   are neat    $1
```

There is no "table" to speak of...